# How is a LEGO Friends Mini-doll built?

Tags: compatibility, friends

Has anyone taken apart a LEGO Friends mini-doll to see how the arms and legs connect? And are the connection points compatible with any other types of brick?

Comment: You can see an exploded view of the mini-doll in [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/964/56), because it comes from a press-pack it doesn't show the arms detached as that's not encouraged ;)

Comment: In fact, re-reading [that question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/959/56) I'd say this was a duplicate :(